# How to remove duplication of columns names using Pandas Merge function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

When we merge two dataframes using pandas merge function, is it possible to ensure the key(s) based on which the two dataframes are merged is not repeated twice in the result? For e.g., I tried to merge two DFs with a column named 'isin_code' in the left DF and a column named 'isin' in the right DF. Even though the column/header names are different, the values of both the columns are same. In, the eventual result though, I get to see both 'isin_code' column and 'isin' column, which I am trying to avoid.

Code used:

```
result = pd.merge(df1,df2[['isin','issue_date']],how='left',left_on='isin_code',right_on = 'isin')
```

Comment: Since the column_names are different, how is pandas suppose to know, which one you wand to keep and which needs to be dropped, so you would have to do that manually by either dropping the column you don't want or renaming the column, so that both matches and only one is retained in the output.

Answer (score 3):

Either [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) the columns to match before [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) to uniform the column names and specify only `on`:

```
result = pd.merge(
    df1,
    df2[['isin', 'issue_date']].rename(columns={'isin': 'isin_code'}),
    on='isin_code',
    how='left'
)
```

OR [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) the duplicate column after merge:

```
result = pd.merge(
    df1,
    df2[['isin', 'issue_date']],
    how='left',
    left_on='isin_code',
    right_on='isin'
).drop(columns='isin')
```

---

Sample DataFrames and output:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'isin_code': [1, 2, 3], 'a': [4, 5, 6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'isin': [1, 3], 'issue_date': ['2021-01-02', '2021-03-04']})
```

`df1`:

```
   isin_code  a
0          1  4
1          2  5
2          3  6
```

`df2`:

```
   isin  issue_date
0     1  2021-01-02
1     3  2021-03-04
```

`result`:

```
   isin_code  a  issue_date
0          1  4  2021-01-02
1          2  5         NaN
2          3  6  2021-03-04
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution above. I did not want to go down the renaming columns option (i.e., option 1 you highlighted), but the second one seems sensible enough.